# MySQL Workbench - Table Data Import CSV Error

Tags: csv, mysql-workbench

I am attempting to import a CSV file using MySQL Workbench Table Data Import Wizard. However, I am running into an error. I have tried changing the import settings.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the line endings and the encoding of the csv file?